# NETWORK_PROVIDER Not Found in Android ICS 4.1

Tags: java, android, gps, location

The Title Say all , im using this :

```
 public int onStartCommand(Intent get,int num1,int num2){

 if (lm != null){

      lm.removeUpdates(this);

  }

 prefs = getSharedPreferences("Prefs", 
         Context.MODE_PRIVATE);





lm = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setAccuracy( Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE );
String provider = lm.getBestProvider( criteria, false );
////* Just GPS is Listed in this List , Google Location is Enabled but Not Detected       
/*and Note the Parameter 'false' to get the list of all avaible provider,enable or not 
Toast.makeText(this, provider, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); */
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 10000, 0, this);




 if(IsFromWidget != true){
str2 = get.getStringExtra("num");   
 }
CheckNetworkState();
return 0;


}

  public void onDestroy() 
 {
 super.onDestroy();
 if (lm != null){

      lm.removeUpdates(this);

  }
 }
private void CheckNetworkState() {


                 if (lm != null){

                      lm.removeUpdates(this);

                  }
                 stopSelf();
                 }






    }





public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

lat = arg0.getLatitude();
lon = arg0.getLongitude();


if (lat == 0 && lon == 0){


}

}


}

if(IsFromWidget = true){



if (lat == 0 && lon == 0){


}
}


stopSelf();
}

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


      } 



public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

 }
```

but its return only GPS and my Google Location Settings are Enabled , and im Connected 3G or Wifi ,its worked fine when i was using Android 2.3.x , please does not pay attention at Code Errors , i Edited the Code before Posting Here .

Thanks .

Comment: Your code formatting is crazy!

Comment: 'lol' i just edited my code and removed some stuff before posting here ...

Answer (score 3):

Remember to set your permissions in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Comment: yes all Permission Required are Set and work fine on Android < 4.x.x

Comment: @Singo das dingo welcome to stackoverflow! I want to notify you that you should not ask questions as an answer.

Comment: @Jordan Richards I thought it was quite informative, as well as a good way to convey the information. I changed it now, as I was obviously way overstepping my mark in my assuptions. Thanks for the pleasant welcome...

Comment: @Singodasdingo, Now the answer is much better! I up voted it for the edit.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get your location you can do this:

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

Criteria crit = new Criteria();
provider = lm.getBestProvider(crit, false);
Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
```

And set up a LocationListener class

```
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc){


    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {


    }


    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }


    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }
}
```

That's a good start for you at least. Good luck!

Comment: Are you using a phone, or are you using an emulator when testing the application? Your code is messy and hard to read so not much help here. Are you trying to let the user know which provider is being used, but it's not showing from your toast, or is the problem that you can't get the location to show?

Comment: No , im using on My Phone Galaxy S2 i9100G running Android 4.1.x , also this is an application to localize a cellphone ...

Comment: and yes* just 'Gps is listed in the Avaibles Providers list , when trying to use Network_Provider i get a Null Pointer Exeption

Comment: Any help so there is no NETWORK_PROVIDER in ICS